# Symfony2 custom authentication : user logged but not authenticated

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, symfony, symfony-2.1

I've been working on a custom authentication system with Symfony 2.1. After a lot of battle with Symfony I've got something that working but not fully...

**Problem** : After the login (through a form), the user is logged but not authenticated.

**Context** : Since users have to submit their credentials through an HTML form, I had to create a listener that extends `AbstractAuthenticationListener`.

**Question** : Shouldn't the listener automatically add the token to the `SecurityContext` ? If this is not the case, should I do that manually ?

**Process** :

> User submits his credentials through HTML form
>
> > Listener intercepts request and runs **attemptAuthentication**
> >
> > > Listener calls AuthenticationManager's (implements AuthenticationProviderInterface) **authenticate** method
> > >
> > > > AuthenticationManager calls the UserProvider (implements UserProviderInterface) to retrieve user's data from my webservice.
> > > >
> > > > UserProvider returns a **User** class implementing UserInterface
> > >
> > > AuthenticationManager creates a **Token** implementing TokenInterface.
> > >
> > > AuthenticationManager returns the token to the listener.
> >
> > Listener's attemptAuthentication returns token from AuthenticationManager's method : authenticate
>
> User is logged but not authenticated.

I haven't shown code samples to avoid overloading the post. If needed I'll edit the post.

Comment: When everything is working properly, all the listener.attemptAuthentication has to do is return the authenticated token which in turn comes from the authenticationManager.authenticate.  No need to explicitly set it in security.context.  First step is to verify that the token is actually authenticated since various other listeners come in to play.  Is the authenticated token a UsernamePasswordToken?

Comment: The authenticated token is an instance of my `CustomToken` as defined in the authenticationManager.support method.

Comment: the description of your process help me a lot to understand the workflow of everything. Im implemeting a custom authentication provider based on BorisMorel LdapBundle and your question asnwered all my questions! Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake...

Once logged in, the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` redirects the user to the url I want. This action triggers a refreshUser from the UserProvider.

This function was hard-coded with a test user different than the user I was logged in with. Once the function returns a user equal to the one stored in the token the problem is solved.